# how can i retrive Win32_ComputerSystem instance in wmi c#?

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

good day for all :)

in this class Win32_SystemDevices class ,  link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-systemdevices) ,

in property GroupComponent  , it is returning an instance of  Win32_ComputerSystem class but i dont find any class in System.Mangment named like this

i think that this property return instance in memory , but how can i catch this instance

i tried some code but i stop here

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ManagementClass diskClass =
         new ManagementClass("Win32_SystemDevices");

        ManagementClass jo = new ManagementClass("Win32_ComputerSystem");


        var disks =
            diskClass.GetInstances();

        foreach (var e in disks)
        {


        }



        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

can any one help me please  , thanks :)

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8572

Comment: Can you clarify a bit?  What is the end result you are looking to achieve.  Win32_ComputerSystem is a valid WMI.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/cimwin32prov/win32-computersystem

@PaulG , from this link there are many properties in Win32_ComputerSystem class that i want to get it from the instance that is returning by property of  Win32_SystemDevices class , i mean that i want to catch the Win32_ComputerSystem instance from Win32_SystemDevices. GroupComponent property , do you understand me broo :) ??

Answer (score 1):

Although the class Win32_ComputerSystem is not technically a singleton class, its treated like one in all of the systems I've seen (I'm curious is anyone has seen this not be the case, comment below.  So in the spirit of a singleton class, it only has one instance.

In the Win32_SystemDevices Class, the property GroupComponent is just a reference to the sole instance in Win32_ComputerSystem you can do so with the following code

```
ManagementObject ComputerSystem = new ManagementObject($@"ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_ComputerSystem.Name='{Environment.MachineName}'");
```

Hopefully this helps.